# send parameters with webview - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using an api, I want to send parameters with this api get method, how can I do this in react-native Web View? For example, this.props.item.SEPETADET I want to send this variable to the email parameter with the get method.

```
<WebView
    style={{ flex : 1, width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 45, height : '100%' }}
    onSizeUpdated={size => console.log(size.height)}



source={{ uri:
     'https:/...php?email=this.props.item.SEPETADET }}
      scalesPageToFit={Platform.select({ android: false})}
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
 />

 </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using plain query parameters, then that is the way to go:

```
source={{ uri: `https:/...php?email=${this.props.item.SEPETADET}` }}
```

But if you want to inject some functionality then you need to use [injectJavaScript](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript) prop.